# spring boot redirecting to login page recursively with valid username and pass

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my security configuration method. Everything was working fine until last night. Now when I try to login to admin dashboard it redirects to the login page on submission. When I use the wrong username and password it shows an error as expected but, if I use a valid username and password it just reloads the login page.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()      
    .httpBasic().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/adminLogin").failureUrl("/adminLogin?error=true")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/dashboard")
    .usernameParameter("email")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .and().logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/adminLogin?logout=true").and().exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/accessdenied");
}
```

Any idea why I am facing this issue?

Comment: are you sure that the user has ADMIN authority? aren't you confusing authority with roled maybe?

Comment: i have ADMIN authority. i was working on this from last 2 months, and start facing this issue from yesterday